# How to show user's answer and the correct answer on the same page after the score page

Tags: php, html

I am currently stuck at the answer page for about a week already, it's very depressing. How do I carry forward what the user have chosen and showed the correct answer in the **worksheet/question** page, when I click "Review Your Answers" button.

Here's my question page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> English Kaki </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <?php include_once"Header.php" ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="container">
                    <center><font color ="#FF9900"><h1>Sentence Structure</h1></font>
                    <p>Be our buddy, construct with us.</p> </center>
                </div>
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#ECEBEB;">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:#ECEBEB;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#ECEBEB;">

            <?php

                $id=isset($_GET['id'])? $_GET['id']: '';
                $data= array(
                'Gws1'              =>array(
                'Name'              =>'Grammar Worksheet 1',
                'Questions'          =>' 
                <form action="SSresultPage.php?id=1" method="post">
                                <fieldset>
                                <ol>
                                        <li>
                                        <p>This is question 1 of Gws1 </p>
                                        <ul id="Gws1_questions1_options">
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions1_options" name="Gws1_questions1_options" type="radio" value="q1 option1" /><label>q1 option1</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions1_options" name="Gws1_questions1_options" type="radio" value="q1 option2" /><label>q1 option2</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions1_options" name="Gws1_questions1_options" type="radio" value="q1 option3" /><label>q1 option3</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions1_options" name="Gws1_questions1_options" type="radio" value="q1 option4" /><label>q1 option4</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </li>

                                        <br>

                                        <li>
                                        <p>This is question 2 of Gws1</p>
                                        <ul id="Gws1_questions2_options">
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions2_options" name="Gws1_questions2_options" type="radio" value="q2 option1" /><label>q2 option1</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions2_options" name="Gws1_questions2_options" type="radio" value="q2 option2" /><label>q2 option2</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions2_options" name="Gws1_questions2_options" type="radio" value="q2 option3" /><label>q2 option3</label></li>

                                        </ul>
                                        </li>

                                        <br>

                                        <li>
                                        <p>This is question 3 of Gws1</p>
                                        <ul id="Gws1_questions1_options">
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions3_options" name="Gws1_questions3_options" type="radio" value="q3 option1" /><label>q3 option1</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions3_options" name="Gws1_questions3_options" type="radio" value="q3 option2" /><label>q3 option2</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Gws1_questions3_options" name="Gws1_questions3_options" type="radio" value="q3 option3" /><label>q3 option3</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </li>

                                </ol>
                                </fieldset> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Get Result"/>
                                </form>'
                ),

                'Gws2'              =>array(
                'Name'              =>'Grammar Worksheet 2',
                'Questions'          =>' <form action="SSresultPage.php?id=2" method="post">

                <input type="submit" value="Get Result"/>
                                </form>'
                ),

                'Gws3'              =>array(
                'Name'              =>'Grammar Worksheet 3',
                'Questions'          =>' <form action="SSresultPage.php?id=3" method="post">

                <input type="submit" value="Get Result"/>
                                </form>'
                ),

                'Vws1'              =>array(
                'Name'              =>'Vocabulary Worksheet 1',
                'Questions'          =>' <form action="SSresultPage.php?id=4" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                                <ol>
                                        <li>
                                        <p>Excuse me, my meal is cold. Could you please ________ for me?</p>
                                        <ul id="Vws1_questions1_options">
                                        <li><input id="Vws1_questions1_options" name="Vws1_questions1_options" type="radio" value="q1 option1" /><label>make it warmer</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Vws1_questions1_options" name="Vws1_questions1_options" type="radio" value="q1 option2" /><label>warm it up</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <br>
                                        <li>
                                        <p>The ________ in most high end restaurants is usually excellent.</p>
                                        <ul id="Vws1_questions2_options">
                                        <li><input id="Vws1_questions2_options" name="Vws1_questions2_options" type="radio" value="q2 option1" /><label>service</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Vws1_questions2_options" name="Vws1_questions2_options" type="radio" value="q2 option2" /><label>responsibility</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <br>
                                        <li>
                                        <p>I felt very _____ after the buffet.</p>
                                        <ul id="Vws1_questions3_options">
                                        <li><input id="Vws1_questions3_options" name="Vws1_questions3_options" type="radio" value="q3 option1" /><label>complete</label></li>
                                        <li><input id="Vws1_questions3_options" name="Vws1_questions3_options" type="radio" value="q3 option2" /><label>full</label></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </li>

                                </ol>
                                </fieldset>         
                <input type="submit" value="Get Result"/>
                                </form>'
                ),

                'Vws2'              =>array(
                'Name'              =>'Vocabulary Worksheet 2',
                'Questions'          =>' <form action="SSresultPage.php?id=5" method="post">

                <input type="submit" value="Get Result"/>
                                </form>'
                ),

                'Vws3'              =>array(
                'Name'              =>'Vocabulary Worksheet 3',
                'Questions'         =>' <form action="SSresultPage.php?id=6" method="post">

                <input type="submit" value="Get Result"/>
                                </form>'
                )
                );


                if(isset($id) || $id){
                echo "<h2>{$data[$id]['Name']}</h2>";
                echo "<h4>Please choose the best option to complete the sentence.</h4>{$data[$id]['Questions']}";
                }

            ?>
        </center>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:#ECEBEB;"></div>

        </div>
    <br><br>
    <?php include_once"Footer.php" ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's my result page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> English Kaki </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <?php include_once"Header.php" ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="container">
                    <center><font color ="#FF9900"><h1>Sentence Structure</h1></font>
                </div>
      <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#ECEBEB;">

            <center>
            <?php
            $fid = $_GET['id'];

                if ($fid == 1){
                    if(!empty($_POST['Gws1_questions1_options']) && !empty($_POST['Gws1_questions2_options']) && !empty($_POST['Gws1_questions3_options'])){
                    $answer1 = $_POST['Gws1_questions1_options'] && $answer2 = $_POST['Gws1_questions2_options'] && $answer3 = $_POST['Gws1_questions3_options'];

                                     $score =0;

                                     if ($answer1 == "q1 option1"){$score++;}
                                     if ($answer2 == "q2 option1"){$score++;}
                                     if ($answer3 == "q3 option1"){$score++;}

                                    echo "<h3>I'm proud of you for completing the worksheet!</h3>";
                                    echo "<h2>Your score is  $score/3</h2><br>";
                                    echo "Review your answers and find out where you went wrong!<br><br>";
                                    echo "<center><form action='SSanswerPage.php'>
                <input type = 'submit' value = 'Review your answers' class='btn'/>
                </form><center><br><br>";
                }                   
                else {
                echo '<p><font color="red">You must answer all questions before you can get your result.</font></p>';
                }}

                elseif ($fid == 2){

                    echo"2";

                }

                elseif ($fid == 3){

                    echo"3";

                }

                elseif ($fid == 4){

                                    $answer1 = $_POST['Vws1_questions1_options'];
                                    $answer2 = $_POST['Vws1_questions2_options'];
                                    $answer3 = $_POST['Vws1_questions3_options'];

                                     $score =0;

                                     if ($answer1 == "q1 option2"){$score++;}
                                     if ($answer2 == "q2 option1"){$score++;}
                                     if ($answer3 == "q3 option2"){$score++;}

                                    echo "<h3>I'm proud of you for completing the worksheet!</h3>";
                                    echo "<h2>Your score is  $score/3</h2><br>";
                                    echo "Review your answers and find out where you went wrong!<br><br>";
                                    echo "<center><form action='SSanswerPage.php'>
                <input type = 'submit' value = 'Review your answers' class='btn'/>
                </form><center><br><br>";

                }

                elseif ($fid == 5){

                    echo"5";

                }

                elseif ($fid == 6){

                    echo"6";

                }
            ?>

        </center>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:#ECEBEB;"></div>

        </div>
    <br><br>
    <?php include_once"Footer.php" ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Only `Grammar Worksheet 1` have questions and can compute score for now.
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: read about sessions. for example: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm or https://www.google.co.il/search?q=php+session+tutorial

Comment: I am aware of the use of $_POST['...']; but how do I post the entire page over to the answer page? And then display the right answer at the side of each question? @Gavriel

Comment: How can I show the answers like this quiz, http://www.myphpquiz.com/question.php?qid=1 . Showing the correct answer with a description in the question itself. Sorry I am really need help with this part @Gavriel

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have Q1, with possible answers A1,A2,A3. You know that the correct answer is Q2, and you see from $_POST['Q1'] == 'A3' that the user answered the wrong answer A3:

css:

```
.user {color:red}
.correct {color:blue}
.correct.user {color:green}
```

php:

```
function is_correct_class($correct_answer, $current_answer, $user_answer) {
  $class = $correct_answer == $current_answer ? 'correct' : '';
  $class .= $user_answer == $current_answer ? ' user' : '';
  return $class;
}

<h2>Q1</h2>
<h3 class="<?php echo is_correct_class('A2', 'A1', $_POST['Q1']);?>;">A1</h3>
<h3 class="<?php echo is_correct_class('A2', 'A2', $_POST['Q1']);?>;">A2</h3>
<h3 class="<?php echo is_correct_class('A2', 'A3', $_POST['Q1']);?>;">A3</h3>
```

Comment: Thank you but... I created a new file "SSanswerPage.php". Users' answers are in question page ? So I put another  <form action="SSanswerPage.php?id=1" method="post"> below <form action="SSresultPage.php?id=1" method="post"> ?  Sorry, I suck at this post function. @gavriel

Comment: Where is the php code suppose to be at? In my question page? :(

Comment: in the answers page. This is what colours the possible questions after you answered

Comment: Am I suppose to replace $correct_answer, $current_answer, $user_answer with 'q1 option1' etc.? Current answer is not need right? Just need to check if correct answer = user answer.. Where did you assign color to the answers in the php code.. sorry I am really lost..

Comment: the css does it. correctly guessed answer: green, when the user made a mistake, he's guess is red, and the correct answer is blue. Colors can be changed in the css.

Comment: What is current answer? @Gavriel

Comment: You use is_correct_class function for all the possible answers: A1,A2,A3. It needs to know which line you are drawing now. So you need to pass it to the function. In this example it's all manually passed for the 3 answers

Comment: Do I get the value from result or question page? @Gavriel

Comment: You'll need to understand the basics of html, form, and a bit of php. Please look for a good tutorial, and get back with some concrete questions